# Post an image to Picasa using Javascript XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, xmlhttprequest, picasa

I am trying to post an image to picasa using javascript. I have got the required tokens. But when I post, I get an error "204 no content"

Here is my code.

```
function send()
{
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
if(xhr.readyState == 4)
alert(xhr.status);
}
xhr.open("POST","https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/albumid/default", true);
var type = document.getElementById('file').files[0].type;
xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept','message/x-jl-formresult');
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type",type);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Length',document.getElementById('file').files[0].size);
xhr.sendAsBinary(document.getElementById('file').files[0].getAsBinary());

}
```

Comment: If you are trying to do that request from an other domain than picasaweb.google.com the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) will block you.

Comment: But he gets a 204 response so that can't be the problem?

Comment: Just to nitpick: "204 No Content" is not an error. The 2xx class is for success codes. To quote the RFC, 204 means "The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the requested variant." http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: @mcb Some browser do use the 204 header result when you are making a cross-domain XHR request.

Comment: I am doing this from an api so ofcourse it must permit me cross domain stuff.

Comment: @Droidme How does the availability of the API guarantee that it is supported by javascript as well, i.e. available cross domain?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what 204 means?

> **204 No Content** The server successfully processed the request, but
>   is not returning any content

[http status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/204_No_Content#2xx_Success)

The server is saying it was good and there is nothing to return.

Comment: But when I upload the photo. I don see them in the picasa album

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with dojo.xhrget, not with your syntax or picasa.   Look in the net panel in firebug and you'll see that dojo.xhrGet does not send the session cookie in the request header s that picasa requires.

Try using jQuery.Get and you'll find it works fine.